# MyBatis-Spring insert a list of objects and retrieve their new IDs

Tags: mysql, spring, list, insert, mybatis

I am working with **MyBatis-Spring** and a **MySql** database. Currently, I am inserting some lists into one of the tables using the following code:

```
<insert id="insertList" parameterType="java.util.List" useGeneratedKeys="true">
        INSERT INTO myTable (field1, field2, field3)
        VALUES
        <foreach collection="list" item="item" separator=",">
            (#{item.field1}, #{item.field2}, #{item.field3})
        </foreach>
    </insert>
```

At this point, I would like to return **the new IDs generated after inserting the new items** without making a new query: SELECT * FROM myTable.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list size is not too large, do loop insert in java code

```
for(Bean bean : list){
   list.insert(bean);
}
```

In mapper.xml insert method should add

```
<selectKey keyProperty="ID" order="AFTER" resultType="java.lang.Integer">
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
</selectKey>
```